# Boggle solver - Updated (with Trie)

Tags: python, python-3.x, trie

Here is an update to my [previous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222546/a-recursive-boggle-solver) boggle solver. The new version has an almost instantaneous output, removing the need to limit the length of words being searched for.

Any comments on my general coding implementation or layout would be appreciated.

```
"""Boggle game solver"""


class Trie:
    """Trie class to speed up programme by stopping exploration of non-existent prefixes"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialise the trie"""
        self.child = {}

    def insert(self, word):
        """Insert word into trie"""
        current = self.child
        for char in word:
            if char not in current:
                current[char] = {}
            current = current[char]

    def search(self, word):
        """Search the trie"""
        current = self.child
        for char in word:
            if char not in current:
                return False
            current = current[char]
        return True


def words_from(board, row, column, running_string, list_words):
    """Calculate all possible words from a given starting position [row, column]"""
    if row in (4, -1) or column in (4, -1):
        return
    # Search the Trie
    if not trie.search(running_string):
        return
    if board[row][column] != "-":
        new_string = running_string + board[row][column]
        board[row][column] = "-"
        # Add new word
        if len(new_string) >= 3:
            list_words.append(new_string.lower())
        # Find next word
        next_move = [
            (1, 1),
            (-1, -1),
            (1, -1),
            (-1, 1),
            (1, 0),
            (0, 1),
            (-1, 0),
            (0, -1),
        ]
        for dx, dy in next_move:
            words_from(board, row + dx, column + dy, new_string, list_words)
        board[row][column] = new_string[-1]
        return list_words


def get_permutations(board):
    """Get all permutations """
    set_permutations = set()
    # Build Trie
    global trie
    trie = Trie()
    with open("en-dict.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
        for line in file:
            trie.insert(line)
    #Search for words from each starting position
    for row in range(4):
        for column in range(4):
            # Search for words
            words = words_from(board, row, column, running_string="", list_words=[])
            if words:
                for word in words:
                    set_permutations.add(word)
            words = None
    return sorted(list(set_permutations))

def dictionary_check(set_permuations):
    """Check set_permutations for valid English words"""
    dictionary = {}
    with open("en-dict.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
        for line in file:
            dictionary[line.strip()] = 0

    counter = 0
    for word in set_permuations:
        if word.lower() in dictionary:
            counter += 1
            print(word)
    print(f"======\n{counter} words")


def find_words(board):
    """Find words on the boggle board"""
    set_permutations = get_permutations(board)
    print("\nPerforming dictionary check....")
    dictionary_check(set_permutations)


def build_board(string):
    """Build board from string"""
    if len(string) != 16:
        print("Error. Must enter 4*4 grid (16 characters)")
        return
    board = [[*string[0:4]], [*string[4:8]], [*string[8:12]], [*string[12:16]]]
    find_words(board)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    string_board = "playthiswordgame"
    build_board(string_board)
```

Comment: A trie is a great option for this. I don't have time for a proper review, but one thing that sticks out as worth mentioning: the same trie structure can both indicate prefixes and indicate whole words in the dictionary. If you added that distinction, you could avoid adding any invalid words to `list_words` in `words_from` in the first place, and therefore avoid needing the additional `dictionary_check` to take them out again afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Rather than a global `Trie` object I would make a `TrieNode` object that inherits from `dict`.

  - This can inherit from `dict`.
  - This can overload `__missing__` to simplify `insert`.
  - Search isn't needed in the way I used it.
- Make a function `build_trie`, that builds and populates the trie from "en-dict.txt".
- `build_board` should really be called `main` and the code that builds the board should be moved into it's own function.
- `find_words` should be moved into `main`.
- `build_trie` should be called from `main` and passed to where it needs to be used.

  When possible don't use `global`. If you think it's impossible, then you're likely wrong.

  In this case you can move the value out of the function into `main` and pass it where it's needed.

  In other cases using a class, a closure or other ways can solve the issue.
- `dictionary_check` should only display words. And the first part of the function can be removed with the new `TrieNode`.
- Move `next_move` out of `words_from`, just make it a global constant.
- `board[row][column] != "-"` relies on mutating `board` I would recommend not mutating input to functions.
- `words_from` can be simplified by passing the current `node`, as then you're not `trie.search`ing.
- In `words_from` `len(new_string) >= 3` is an artificial limitation, that should be moved out of the function.
- `get_permutations` can be simplified by changing `words_from` to return an empty list on bad input.
- I would move `set_permutations` out of `get_permutations`, as it doesn't have much purpose in that function.
- I merged `words_from` and `set_permutations` to use a `while` loop, I found this to make the code easier to understand and make.
- Don't `print` and `return`, use `raise`.

---

For the most part your code seems to be fairly good, there's some pitfalls your falling down. But on a micro - line by line - scale your code is pretty good.

The problem I saw with your code is not seeing the big picture, and not following SRP.

Improving SRP should be fairly easy for you. If you're thinking of putting a comment that says the code is performing a different task, move it into a function.

To help with the big picture, when you follow SRP think to yourself if you should split the code into 2/3 functions and should call the three functions in succession. Like I changed `main` to do.

---

```
class TrieNode(dict):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = value

    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = TrieNode()
        self[key] = value
        return value

    def insert(self, word):
        current = self
        for char in word:
            current = current[char]
        current.value = word


def build_trie():
    trie = TrieNode()
    with open("en-dict.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
        for line in file:
            trie.insert(line.strip())
    return trie


def board_from_string(string):
    if len(string) != 16:
        raise ValueError("Must enter 4*4 grid (16 characters)")
    return [
        [*string[0:4]],
        [*string[4:8]],
        [*string[8:12]],
        [*string[12:16]]
    ]


AROUND = [
    (dx, dy)
    for dx in range(-1, 2)
    for dy in range(-1, 2)
    if not (dx == dy == 0)
]


def get_words(trie, board):
    stack = []
    for row in range(4):
        for column in range(4):
            stack.append((trie, row, column, set()))
    while stack:
        node, row, column, parents = stack.pop()
        if row in (4, -1) or column in (4, -1) or (row, column) in parents:
            continue
        char = board[row][column]
        if char not in node:
            continue
        node = node[char]
        if node.value is not None:
            yield node.value
        for dx, dy in AROUND:
            stack.append((node, row + dx, column + dy, parents | {(row, column)}))


def display(words):
    words = sorted({w for w in words if len(w) >= 3})
    print('\n'.join(words))
    print(f"======\n{len(words)} words")


def main():
    string = "playthiswordgame"
    trie = build_trie()
    board = board_from_string(string)
    words = get_words(trie, board)
    display(words)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Using the binary operator is pretty smart. Also very clever to inherit the ```dict``` class. Didn't think about that. Thank you